# Confusing usage of ‘met’ in this sentence

Tags: structure, verb-pattern

I don’t know why there is the word “met” in this sentence:

> *"But as always, he did **check it met** with our approval too."*

What pattern or structure is it?

Comment: @lee A comma there looks wrong to me, a native speaker. It makes the "it met ..." a run-on sentence. "it met" is directly consequential to "check" and putting a comma there separates it off so that is no longer the case. Then it reads: "But as always, he did check. It met with our approval too." Which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence omits an optional "that". It is equivalent to "...he did check that it met with our approval too." *Check* here means to confirm or verify. For something to *meet with a person's approval* is another way of saying that the person approves of it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a case of omitting the subordinator "that":

> he did check that it met with our approval too..